# IHttpActionResult and helper methods in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-core

I'm trying to move my web api 2 project to ASP.NET 5.
But I have many elements that are not present anymore.

For example `IHttpActionResult` or `Ok(), NotFound()` methods.
Or `RoutePrefix`[]

Should I change every `IHttpActionResult` with `IActionResult` ? 
Change `Ok`() with `new ObjectResult` ? (is it the same ?)

What about `HttpConfiguration` that seems no more present in startup.cs ?

Comment: Even though there is a `WebApiComatShim` package in MVC 6 for this kind of portability scenarios, its recommended not to use it, So I would suggest to use the new MVC 6 way of doing things.

Comment: Regarding HttpConfiguration, have you looked at how the new `Startup.cs` looks like? Can you try moving it there?

Comment: the new mvc 6 way of doing this ... ok, but is return Ok(mydata) equivalent to return new ObjectResult(mydata) { StatusCode = 200 }; ?

Comment: for httpconfiguration, i will try to do otherwise thanks

Comment: yes, what you have for `Ok` seems fine (you need not explicitly set the status code in this case...it should default to 200)....you could write your own base controller with these helper methods so that you need not change it in multiple controllers...

Comment: Related post - [IHttpActionResult vs IActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51480689/465053)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`IHttpActionResult` is now effectively `IActionResult`, and to return an `Ok` with a return object, you'd use `return new ObjectResult(...);`

So effectively something like this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    if (id == 1) return HttpNotFound("not found!");
    return new ObjectResult("value: " + id);
}
```

Here's a good article with more detail:

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6

Comment: Shouldn't he use `return Ok("value" + id)` ?
`Ok()` is still there and seems the reasonable way to represent a 200-Ok response from the API.

Comment: @CesarD yes in the latest releases it has gone back to `NotFound`, `Ok`, etc.

Comment: It's a real shame Microsoft can't preserve its own documentation online.  That URL now redirects to the (an?) ASP.NET homepage.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated reply-ish**

I saw that someone referenced the `WebApiCompatShim` in a comment.

`WebApiCompatShim` is still maintained for this kind of portability scenarios and it is now released 1.1.0.

I saw that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 1.0.0-rtm-00011` has `WebApiCompatShim` as a dependency. I don't know exactly what they are trying to achieve in this area, these are just facts.

If you're not into getting another compatibility package and you're looking into more refactoring work, you can look at the following approach: [WebApiCompatShim - how to configure for a REST api with MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540431/webapicompatshim-how-to-configure-for-a-rest-api-with-mvc-6)

You will still be able to use `Ok()` or you can try to use the `OkObjectResult()` method as Http word was removed in order not to be too verbose. `HttpOkObjectResult` -> `OkObjectResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new {Name= "test", id=1};
    return new OkObjectResult(item);
}


[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new {Name= "test", id=1};
    return Ok(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At 2.2, the ASP.NET Core migration guide states to replace IHttpActionResult with ActionResult.  This works for me:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSomeTable([FromBody] GridState state)
{
  return Ok(new
  {
    data = query.ToList(),
    paging = new
      {
        Total = total,
        Limit = state.limit,
        page = state.page,
        Returned = query.Count()
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't replacing it with IActionResult be more in keeping?