# WebApiCompatShim - how to configure for a REST api with MVC 6

Tags: migration, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was having a look at [this link](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-startup-file-in-asp-net-5-what-does-it-do/) that shows how to migrate from Web API 2 to MVC 6.

I am trying to have Action methods in my controllers with the `HttpRequestMessage` bound. This works in Web Api 2.

```
 [Route("", Name = "AddTaskRoute")]        
 [HttpPost]        
 public Task    AddTask(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, [FromBody]NewTask newTask)
 {            
      var task = _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor.AddTask(newTask); 
      return task;         
 }
```

and the requestMessage contains the details about the Http request such as headers, verb, etc.

I am trying to get the same with MVC 6 but the requestMessage seems to be incorrectly bound and it shows details such as the method being GET when the action is actually a POST. I believe I haven't configured the WebApiCompatShim as per the article suggests so the binding is not properly done. But I do not have the extension method `services.AddWebApiConventions();` available in the version `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`

Anybody has succeed when trying this?

PS: The `Request` property available in my controller seems to have details about the http request, but I'd like to have the `HttpRequestMessage` instance.

Comment: What specific information are you missing when you use `Request` ?

Comment: ```Request``` property is correct. However I'd like to use the ```HttpRequestMessage``` instance to use its method CreateResponse() so that when a resource is created it returns a 201 to that request. This is how it was in Web Api 2

Comment: You should be able to get all those with MVC6 as well. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MVC6, You should be able to use the `Request` object to get header information.

```
var contentTypeHeader = Request.Headers["Content-Type"];
```

It is true that they removed some of the nice methods like `Request.CreateResponse()` and `OK()` etc.. But there are some alternatives you can use.

All of these classes we will be using to create a response are inheriting from the `ObjectResult` base class. So you can use `ObjectResult` as the return type of your Web api method.

### HttpOKObjectResult

In MVC6, You can use create an object of `HttpOKObjectResult` class and use that as your return value instead of `Request.CreateResponse()`. This will produce the status code `200 OK` for the response.

**Web API2 code**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new { Name= "test", id = 1 };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,item);
}
```

**MVC 6 code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new {Name= "test", id=1};
    return new HttpOkObjectResult(item);
}
```

Or simply use the `OK()` method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new {Name= "test", id=1};
    return Ok(item);
}
```

### CreatedAtRouteResult

You can use `CreatedAtRouteResult` class to send a response with `201 Created` status code with a location header.

**MVC 6 code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var item = new { Name= "test", id=250};
    return new CreatedAtRouteResult(new { id = 250}, item);
}
```

The client will receive a `location` header in the response which will point to the api route with 250 as the value for the id parameter.

### HttpNotFoundObjectResult

You can use this class to return a `404 Not found` response.

**Web API2 code**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);   
}
```

**MVC 6 code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundObjectResult("Some");
}
```

Comment: Http word was removed in order not to be too verbose. `HttpOkObjectResult` -> `OkObjectResult`

Answer (score 1):

I found that to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim, it should be `services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions()` [see this example](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2bc4c40485b799418bb50fbafa156a9487b372c1/test/WebSites/WebApiCompatShimWebSite/Startup.cs) instead of `services.AddWebApiConventions()` as shown in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

I'm putting in a feedback item on their docs.

Comment: and it has been fixed (see my issue link)