# How to create a response in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this code in MVC 4:

```
private HttpResponseMessage GetAuthToken(Guid userId)
        {
            var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(userId);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Authorized");
            response.Headers.Add("Token", token.AuthToken);
            response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthTokenExpiry"]);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");

            return response;
        }
```

How I can migrate this code to MVC 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for MVC 6.

```
public ObjectResult GetAuthToken(Guid userId)
{
  var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(userId);
  var r = new HttpOkObjectResult(token);

  Response.Headers.Add("Token", token.AuthToken);
  Response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthTokenExpiry"]);
  Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");

  return r;
}
```

Or simply the `Ok` method

```
public ObjectResult GetAuthToken(Guid userId)
{
  var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(userId);
  Response.Headers.Add("Token", token.AuthToken);
  Response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthTokenExpiry"]);
  Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");

  return Ok(token);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540431/webapicompatshim-how-to-configure-for-a-rest-api-with-mvc-6/34540972#34540972) is a list of samples to convert from Web Api 2 MVC 6.