# IHttpActionResult vs IActionResult

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I'm creating an API using .NET Core 2 to provide data for many applications developed in different technologies. I'm currently returning `IActionresult` from my methods. I've been studying what the best option is to return the data and saw some examples using `IHttpActionResult`. Now I dont't know which type is the best to return.

What is the difference between `IHttpActionResult` and `IActionresult`?

Comment: "IActionResult is the new abstraction that should be used in your actions. Since Web API and MVC frameworks have been unified in ASP.NET Core, various IActionResult implementations can handle both traditional API scenarios.". Check https://forums.asp.net/t/2097282.aspx?IHttpActionResult+vs+IActionResult and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1149/convert-aspnet-webapi2-aspnet5-mvc6

Comment: Actually, since 2.1, you should use `ActionResult<T>` instead of `IActionResult` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type

Comment: @p3tch thx. I didant know that

Comment: To be clear. There's no specific recommendation one way or another for `IActionResult` vs. `ActionResult<T>`. You may certainly choose to use `ActionResult<T>`, but it's not required.

Comment: Related post - [IHttpActionResult and helper methods in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30511864/465053)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`IHttpActionResult` is for ASP.NET Web Api, while `IActionResult` is for ASP.NET Core. There's no such thing as "Web Api" in ASP.NET Core. It's all just "Core". However, some people still refer to creating an ASP.NET Core API as a "Web Api", which adds to the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. So can I get so excited about using IActionResult because it's good practice?

Comment: It's just a common and clean way to use `IActionResult` since it allows you to return all results which implements `IActionResult`.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you should always use either `IActionResult` or `ActionResult<T>`, as opposed to return specific types like `MyJsonObject` or even specific result types, like `JsonResult`.

Comment: Even Microsoft themselves sometimes refer to an ASP.NET Core Web API. e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Yeah. I think they do it as a way to transition people who are familiar only with ASP.NET Web Api, but it ends up just confusing everything. There's no practical difference in Core, and when you search for "Web Api", you just end up getting a bunch of wrong, outdated information.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: they do so because when creating a core web application one of the internal templates visual studio provides selection for is "API" (among API, Web Application, Web Application MVC, etc)

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Based on my comment immediately above, it would make sense to refer to "ASP.NET Core API" (the confusion is inherited from Visual Studio's core web project template...)

Comment: Yeah, I find the templates annoying in that way. They're really just starter projects, geared to one type or another, but it creates the presumption that you're making some irreversible choice, where this thing is always going to be an API project or an MVC project. Any ASP.NET Core project can be anything or any combination of things.

Comment: 4 years later:  "In ASP.NET Core, there's no longer any distinction between MVC and Web APIs." : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/webapi-differences

Comment: Which one to use in .NET 6 webapi?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what version of `ASP.NET` you are going to use. That can either be the `.NET Core` version or the traditional one.

As mentioned by Chris you can only use `IActionResult` in `ASP.NET Core`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#iactionresult-type

> I'm creating an API

Well, if you are using the traditional `ASP.NET` - instead of `.NET Core` you are fine with using `IHttpActionResult`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results, otherwise stick with `IActionResult`.

Comment: I'm using .net core 2

Comment: Then stick to `IActionResult`, this is very useful since you can return anything with that interface. Think of `Ok()`, `BadRequest()` etc.