# What is difference between IActionResult and IHttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What is difference between IActionResult and IHttpActionResult

IActionResult and IHttpActionResult

Comment: `IHttpActionResult` is an interface from "old" iteration of framework. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `IHttpActionResult` for Asp.Net core (lastest version 7) ,it's just for old Asp.Net (or call .NetFramework ,highest version 4.8.1). You can only use `IActionResult` for .Net Core project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480689/ihttpactionresult-vs-iactionresult